# Different output when trying to grep and awk CPU % from xentop

Tags: bash, shell, awk, xen

I have set up an ssh connection from my mac to XenServer. I'm able to get the metrics for CPU and memory using `xentop` command as shown below

[image]

Further, I wanted to get the CPU utilization using a bash script so that I So that I can get the average values for this, as shown below.

[image].

As you can see in the above figure, The problem I'm facing is that the first value is coming out to be zero, followed by other values. For all the times the first value always comes as 0. Can someone please explain what I'm doing wrong.

PS: The `-bi3` means that the command will be executed thrice.

Please let me know if you have any questions.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: What do you get out of `xentop -bi3`? Always add your code and output as plain text formatted for SO.

Comment: If it's the same as plain old `top` the first output for Cpu in batch mode is basically useless and should be ignored; see the BUGS section of the man page. PS: `awk` can do almost everything `grep` can do including this one.

Comment: Per above, `xentop -bi4 | awk '/Domain/ { if(c++) print $4 }` should fix your problem.